# How to bind dictionary<string,object> in asp.net core for entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My model includes a property that contains raw json values. I am using entity framework core 3 and dot net core 3.

```
[Table("test")]
public class PostData
{
    [Column("id"), Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("properties"), JsonExtensionData]
    public virtual Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; } 
}
```

And I mapped in my db context.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostData>(b =>
        {
            b.Property(u => u.Properties)
                .HasConversion(
                    d => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d),
                    s => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(s)
                )
                .HasMaxLength(5000)
                .IsRequired();
        });
    }
```

So When I post a data from asp.net core,

```
{
    "name": "x",
    "properties": {
        "color": "red",
        "size": "L"
    }
}
```

Action is:

```
    [HttpPost("create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] PostData data)
    {
        await using var context = new MyDbContext();

        await context.Post.AddAsync(data);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return await Task.FromResult(Ok(data));
    }
```

[image]

It saves `properties` to database like following.

```
{"color":{"ValueKind":3},"size":{"ValueKind":3}}
```

Why does not serialize?

Comment: I try to understand the problem :d your Property object is serialized and saved into db as json value. This must do the SerializeObject,  right? from object (data.Property) to json

Comment: sorry, now I see...you reffer at "ValueKind"

Comment: It can be due of your Dictionary definition, SerializeObject don't know the type of "object" and probably save it with "ValueKind: x". Do you tried to use <string, string> instead <string, object> ? just for test :d

Comment: I updated the post with model binding breakpoint.

Comment: Is strange. I test a dictionary with <string, object> and result is ok: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KcRjGq

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking a shot in the dark here based on the presence of "ValueKind" in the data. `ValueKind` is a property of `JsonElement` in `System.Text.Json`. Everywhere else, you're using JSON.NET, and in particular, the `JsonExtensionData` attribute is from JSON.NET. I'd imagine that you haven't actually fully replaced `System.Text.Json`, and that, rather than JSON.NET, is being used during the model binding phase. See the [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#newtonsoftjson-jsonnet-support) for details on how to use JSON.NET instead.